# Defining stdout and stderr in a child.process in node.js 8

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to start. child process in my node dev-server, to set the API json-server before launching it when I use the command :

```
nom run dev -- reset
```

I am stuck with the stdout and stderr parameters being null, with the error :

cp.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null

here is my piece of code. Feedback appreciated...

```
  const cp = spawn('cp', [dbResetJson, dbJson], { stdio: 'inherit' })
  cp.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });
  cp.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });
  cp.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`)
    apiServer.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log(chalk.green('Starting DB-JSON test Server... at ' + '3000' + '\n'))
    })
  })
} else {
  console.log(chalk.green('Use DB-JSON test Server in current state'))
  apiServer.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(chalk.green('Starting DB-JSON test Server... at ' + '3000' + '\n'))
  })
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cp.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(er);
}); ? Maybe your spawn failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're using `stdio: 'inherit'`, which means that the child process will use the parent process's `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` (in which case it doesn't make sense to attach a listener to `stdout`).

You probably want to just use the default (`pipe`):

```
const cp = spawn('cp', [dbResetJson, dbJson]);
// which does the same as:
const cp = spawn('cp', [dbResetJson, dbJson], { stdio: 'pipe' });
```